# McCormick envelope for a linear variaable

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-geometry

I would like to ask about obtaining a McCormick envelope for a single linear variable x (not x^2). Can I just say envelope>=x and envelope <=x?

Comment: The function $x \mapsto x$ is already convex. Why do you need a McCormick envelope of it?

Comment: I have a variable x multiplied by an envelope. How should I deal with that?